# True/false: $f(x)=x^4-x^3+14x^2+5x+16$ is the product of two degree two polynomials over $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: polynomials

> Is  the following statement is true/false?
>
> Consider the polynomial $$f(x)=x^4-x^3+14x^2+5x+16,$$  then $f$ is a product of two polynomials of degree two over $\mathbb{Z}$.

My answer : I think it will be true $f(x)=x^4-x^3+14x^2+5x+16=  (x^2 +ax+b)(x^2 +cx + d)$

Is its  True ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: you have begun properly. Using your letters $a,b,c,d,$ what is the required value for $a+c?$

Comment: @WillJagy give me 3 minutes  im calculating

Comment: I actually can wait... however, what I do is to multiply out JUST ENOUGH to figure out $a+c.$ Then I go on to another easy one, such as what is the product $bd \; ? \; \;$ My point is, mutlitplying out the whole thing in symbols makes a bit of a mess;

Comment: @WillJagy $a+ c = -1$

Comment: I thought of a good one, since all must be integers. First, what is $bd \; ? \;$ Second, what is $ad+bc ?$  The two facts put together make something nice using odd/even numbers.

Comment: bd =16  @ Will jagy

Comment: Alright, a caution: either both $b,d > 0$ or both $b,d < 0.$ Anyway, $bd$ is even. Now, what is $ad+bc \; ? \;$ And, this is the first punchline, can $b,d$ both be even?

Comment: Try searching Eisenstein's theorem.

Comment: too many people; as far as we had gotten, as  $ad+bc$ is odd, we find that one of $b,d$ is odd, so the total possibilities for ordered $(b,d)$ are $(1,16),$ $(-1,-16),$ $(16,1),$ $(-16,-1),$ For each pair one may, well, continue with $c=(1-a)$ written in, see what happens

Comment: @WillJagy sir  can u explain  ur  answer in detail   in answer BOX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: the image of $f(x)$ in $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})[x]$ is $x^4 + x^3 + x = x(x^3 + x^2 + 1)$.  However, $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in this ring (why?).  Can you complete the proof to show that this implies that the original polynomial cannot be a product of two quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: why  u  take  $\mathbb{Z_2}$??   question is about  $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @jasmine Show that if a polynomial were a product of two quadratics in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, it would also be in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Comment: okkss  @CarlSchildkraut..thanks u  i gots  its ....   can u  said  me  that  which theorem  is  this ?

Comment: I don't think there's any particular theorem - just the fact that the function $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})[x]$, $\sum a_i x^i \mapsto \sum \overline{a_i} x^i$, is a ring homomorphism.  (Do note, however, that the proof will make use in an essential way of the fact that $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})[x]$ is a unique factorization domain - for which you probably do have a theorem to cite to justify this fact.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks u,  got its